# Intuition on the external Zappa–Szép product

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, intuition, semidirect-product

$\newcommand{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}$A classmate of mine recently posted an interesting question on Facebook. It didn't get an answer, and I couldn't get anywhere myself, so I'm hoping that someone here will be able to help out.

Here's a paraphrase of the question:

> The Zappa–Szép product generalizes the semi-direct product, which
>   itself is a generalization of the direct product. They've all got
>   roughly the same conditions for the "internal" product:
>
> - $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of some parent group $G$
> - $H \cap K = \{ e \}$
> - $HK = G$
> - Normality:
>
>   - Direct: $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$
>   - Semidirect: $K$ is normal in $G$
>   - Zappa-Szép: no further assumptions
>
> But usually, people use this products in their "external" forms. For
>   these three, we need different amounts of additional data describing how the
>   groups commute.
>
> For the direct product $H \times K$, we need no further information. For
>   a semidirect product $H \rtimes_\varphi K$, we also need a homomorphism
>   $\varphi : H \to \Aut(K)$.
>
> So for the Zappa-Szép product, one might expect to have two
>   homomorphisms: $\alpha : K \to \Aut(H)$ and $\beta : H \to \Aut(K)$.
>   But as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product)
>   explains, one of the conditions we need is that
>   $$ \alpha(k, h_1 h_2) = \alpha(k, h_1) \cdot \alpha(\beta(h_1, k), h_2) $$
>
> But if $\alpha(k)$ were an automorphism of $H$, then the condition would
>   just be
>   $$ \alpha(k, h_1 h_2) = \alpha(k, h_1) \cdot \alpha(k, h_2) $$
>
> This makes sense from a multiplication perspective, because as we pull
>   the $k$ to the right of $h_1$, it will become a different element of
>   $K$. But it's rather unappetizing from a morphism perspective.
>
> Is there a way to phrase this additional data more elegantly?

Here's my thoughts so far: $\alpha$ might not be a homomorphism into $\Aut(H)$, but it's still a left group action of $K$ on $H$. Same for $\beta$, except it's a right group action. So that takes care of the first five conditions from the wiki page. So now we just need to rephrase the last two conditions in a group-action-friendly way. But I can't seem to do so.

Alternatively, maybe we should think of this as a single map $\psi : K \times H \to H \times K$. But I can't think of any natural, morphism-ish qualities that this map must have.